# How to integrate Material Components Web with an Angular CLI project?

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-cli

I'm following the [Getting Started](https://material.io/components/web/) instructions for adding Material Components for web, and I'm getting the following error on Step 4:

```
<script>mdc.autoInit()</script>
-> Uncaught ReferenceError: mdc is not defined at (index):17
```

As mentioned, this is an Angular CLI project, so the script is being loaded from the `.angular-cli.json` file:

```
"scripts": [
    "../node_modules/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.js"
]
```

Is there another place in the CLI setup I should be loading the file, or making the call to `mdc.autoInit()`?

I've also looked at the [Angular 2 Framework Integration](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/tree/master/framework-examples) example, and it was no help. It doesn't use the CLI, and it never calls `mdc.autoInit()`.

Answer (score -1):

In every project there is an `index.html` file. You need to put your scripts there.